# Attribution of the quote "a mathematician is someone who is cautious in the presence of the obvious"

Tags: ho.history-overview

A few years ago I came across a quote attributed to a well-known mathematician: "a mathematician is someone who is cautious in the presence of the obvious". I really like this quote but I can't figure out who said it - does anyone know?

Comment: This does not seem to be a question in research-level mathematics, or even a reference request in the sense in which that is usually understood here.

Comment: perhaps a paraphrase of E.T. Bell's quote: "_Obvious_ is the most dangerous word in mathematics."

Answer (score 15):

Eric Temple Bell, The Development of Mathematics, page 76: "Like Euclid in his explicit statement of the parallel postulate, Archimedes had the true mathematician's caution in the presence of the obvious."

Comment: That's the only Google hit for "caution in the presence of the obvious".